# Powerdot and enumerate - no worky?

Tags: lists, enumerate, powerdot

Thanks to the site for the tip about replacing prosper with powerdot. That fixed some of my problems (margins are there now). Unfortunately it also seems to have created another one. Namely the enumerate-environment no longer works. Here's the source code to the first slide

```
\documentclass{powerdot}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[Finnish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,enumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{slide}{Propositioiden totuustauluista}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Propositioista eri tavoin kombinoimalla  muodostettujen
propositioiden totuusarvoja voidaan tutkia ns. totuustaulun avulla
\item Totuustaulussa on yksi vaakarivi kutakin `alkeispropositioiden'
totuusarvojen kombinaatiota kohti.
\item Jos alkeispropositioita on $n$ kappaletta, rivej\"a tulee $2^n$ kappaletta.
\item Sarakkeilla on otsikkorivill\"a kerrottu, mink\"a proposition totuusarvo
kyseisell\"a sarakkeella on.
\end{enumerate}
\end{slide}
\end{document}
```

This gives a

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `lastslide' on page 1 undefined on input line 28
```

and more seriously

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\enit@endenumerate ->\enit@after
                                \endlist \ifx \enit@series \relax \else \if ...
l.28 \end{slide}
```

Can someone diagnose this problem? I first tried to update/install prosper packages. Only when I learned that I need to move to powerdot, did I install powerdot (or rather let the automatic installation do it for me). Should I have uninstalled something in between?

When I replace *enumerate* with *itemize*, the error messages disappear. The LaTeX warning disappears on the second run, so presumably it is just about something in the .aux file, and unrelated to my problem.

System: Windows 7, WinEdt 7.0, MiKTeX 2.9

Comment: I guess that `powerdot` loads `enumitem`, which is not compatible with `enumerate`, but it's much more powerful, so you never need `enumerate`.

Comment: @egreg yes, that's what happens. You should turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `powerdot` class loads `enumitem`:

```
188 \RequirePackage{enumitem}[2007/03/12]
```

(188 is the line number in `powerdot.cls`). This package is much more powerful than `enumerate`: nothing that can be done with the latter can't be obtained as easily with the former, which can also do much more.

Since those packages fight for redefining the `enumerate` environment, *you* lose.

The key to my guess was the `enit@` bit in the error message: `enit@` is the common prefix for private macros of `enumitem`.

---

Note that the correct call for `babel` is

```
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
```

With a capital “F” it may work with some systems (when the file system is case insensitive). It will definitely not work on any system with `babel` version 3.9, so it's better you fix it.

Comment: Thanks. A little bit of testing reveals that the only change I had to make in my source code was to remove *enumerate* from that last `\usepackage` command.

Comment: Thank you, I removed `\usepackage{enumitem}` and error is gone.